# Export :PROPERTIES: blocks with org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

The `org-mode` manual says that it's possible to [export property drawers](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html), but trying with

```
 #+OPTIONS: d:t
```

does not export any `:PROPERTIES:` blocks like it used to.

Reading the [Drawers chapter](http://orgmode.org/manual/Drawers.html) it seems it is indeed not possible anymore, at least with the latest `org-mode` version:

> You can select the name of the drawers which should be exported with org-export-with-drawers. In that case, drawer contents will appear in export output. **Property drawers are *not* affected by this variable and are *never* exported.**

Is there any tweak to regain that functionality, i.e. having `#+OPTIONS: d:t` export the whole `:PROPERTIES:` block, short of manually changing the `.org` file before export time?

Comment: You can't export the whole block, but you can use [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/156/emacs-function-to-convert-an-arbitrary-org-property-into-an-arbitrary-string-na?rq=1) code to export specific properties.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful, but if one needs to have all of `PROPERTIES`,  it would be nice to have an option to just expose all of them at publish time, in whatever export format one would need. For now, I have a small function that wraps the `PROPERTIES` block inside a `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE` block, but that solution if far from pleasing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you can use `#+OPTIONS: prop:t` instead.

From [12.3 Export settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html):

> `prop`:
>   Toggle inclusion of property drawers, or list properties to include (`org-export-with-properties`).

Comment: Wonderful, that switch must have appeared in org-mode 8.3.x. Thank you.